# Picking up multiple from items using JSQLParser

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsqlparser

I am writing a SQL query evaluator and I am using JSQLParser for parsing the query. Now it seems (and also suggested by this link http://sourceforge.net/p/jsqlparser/feature-requests/2/ ) that JSQLParser does not allow multiple items in the FROM Clause of SQL.

When I do

```
statement.getFromItem().toString();
```

where statement is an object of type `PlainSelect`, I get only the first tablename from the FROM Clause. There is no `toArray()` method in the FromItem Class.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact JSQLParser is able to parse your statement or your mentioned example:

```
select t1.a, t2.b from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id
```

The second table is not recognized as a second **FromItem** but as a **simple Join**. To get your tables you need to look into **getJoins** as well.

Here is my test code, which is written using the fork of JSqlParser at github https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser.

```
public class MultiFromItems {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSQLParserException {
        String sql = "select t1.a, t2.b from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id";
        Statement parse = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
        Select select = (Select)parse;
        PlainSelect ps = (PlainSelect)select.getSelectBody();
        System.out.println(ps);
        System.out.println(ps.getFromItem());
        System.out.println(ps.getJoins().get(0));
    }
}
```